# # sign is not working properly for URL access check in spring security 5

Tags: spring-security, grails-5, spring-security-5

I am upgrading a project from grails 2.5.2 to grails 5.2.5 version.
In previous version spring security 2 has been used. There URL access check start with # sign works fine.
But in upgrading version, the same URL check is returning true although the user don't have permission. For example consider the following code

In requestmap table for this url - `/#Customer` only `ROLE_MANAGER` has permission.
But for `ROLE_USER` this URL access is returning true from the below method.

```
 ...
defaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed("/#Customer", springSecurityService.getAuthentication())
...
```